# Can we use fork/join and executor service at the same time in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

In essence, I am coding an algorithm that involves summing all numbers in a big array, each of which takes a parameter. And I have a bunch of parameters to run. To me, the summing of all numbers can be a good candidate of leveraging fork/join in Java, and running the algorithm with different parameter can be effectively done with fixed pool of executor service.

However, anyone knows how to combine those two? Or is it possible to combine them, considering that they are both thread pools and we should not have two pools at the same time?

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one pool, and submit all tasks to this pool.

The main question is how many threads the pool should have (the parallelism). You can start with the default (N=number of processors) and test throughputs with different parallelism. My guess is the peak throughput is at somewhere between N and 2N.

In Java 8, there is even a [common pool](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) :

> A static commonPool() is available and appropriate for most applications.

The nice thing about FJP is that the performance is near optimal and not sensitive to tuning (as long as config is within reasonable range, say, not 10*N threads)

Comment: Thanks for the post. Currently with Java 7, if there is only one pool, will it be newFixedThreadPool (for executors, since I know how many parameters I need to try), or ForkJoinPool (for fork/join to speed up addition)? How can I use one pool to support both? However, two pools do not sound reasonable to me. BTW, I assume that the pool needs to be a singleton right?

Comment: ForkJoinPool is a ExecutorService, you can submit ordinary tasks to it

Comment: 1. How can I leverage the knowledge of number of parameters (thus number of threads)? 2. It is hard to write those parallel tasks (only different in parameters) as RecursiveTask, unlike additions. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

As zhong.j.yu said, the number ot pools is not as important as the number of simultaneously active threads in those pools combined.

A ForkJoinPool is most appropriate for tasks the lend themselves to subdivision/combination schemes, as hinted by the name `RecursiveTask`. They may not be the best choice for summing up array values, which sounds like a cache/memory-limited kind of task.

You should do some profiling or at least experimenting with the number of threads, as cache thrashing will limit performance at some point.

ForkJoinPool is highly optimized (check the class comments), much more so than ThreadPoolExecutor, but for memory-limited jobs, you will not notice the difference.

In my experience, each task submitted to either pool should take at least 100µs for optimum balance. Many small jobs may provide best thread utilization, but there is a cost in overhead for handling all the Runnables in the job queue.